# what event is activated when data is added to an iframe after POST

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has an iframe target on the same page. When the form has successfully submitted it writes something to the iframe. When that happens, I then want other things to happen, too. I will do this via jquery/javascript. But what event is activated by this? Or, is there another event that is activated when the submit is completed.

(The reason I'm doing this is instead of using AJAX for file submission in Django. I don't want to use AJAX because it causes a whole other set of issues with submitting a file to my django Form.)

Answer (score 0):

Posting back causes a full page refresh so you should be able to put your post-submission code in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // solve all of the world's problems
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't refresh the full page. I put an alert inside $(document).ready(function () and it is only called when the page first loads, not after the iframe is filled. I'm writing a solution up now...

Comment: which was not saved... (trying again). now it's there

Comment: @user984003: I removed it. Read my comment under your question please.

Comment: Well, a heads up would have been nice. I didn't save my solution and I'm not writing it out a third time! Also, it doesn't make sense that I can't answer my own question. Why should other people spend time when I already have a solution that works? This comment field doesn't work well for writing long solutions. Oh well.